# Sum two rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sum

Consider the following matrix:

```
mat <- cbind(c(5,2,5),c(6,3,2))
```

I want to sum the two first rows, so I get the following matrix:

```
7 9
5 2
```

How do I do that in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `rowsum`:

```
> rowsum(mat, c(1,1,2))
  [,1] [,2]
1    7    9
2    5    2
```

The first argument is your matrix `mat`, the second one specifies how the rows should be grouped together. Here `c(1,1,2)` specify that first two rows are in one group (and summed together) and the third row is in another group.

Note: Do not confuse this with `rowSums` - a different function.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `colSums` to sum first `n` rows and `rbind` remaining ones

```
n <- 2
rbind(colSums(mat[seq_len(n), ]), mat[(n + 1):nrow(mat), ])
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    7    9
#[2,]    5    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I have a huge matrix where I - for instance - want to sum row 1 and 3; 5 and 7; 11 and 24 and so on. Can I still use your code?

Comment: @Michael No..This sums up only first `n` rows. How are these combinations stored ? 1 and 3, 5 and 7 etc ?